# Git pull taking infinite time

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am trying to pull the recent changes from develop branch. It was pulling correct till yesterday, Suddenly now git pull taking infinite time. not sure what is the issue.

Attached the screenshot, the progress not happening it stucks here more than hour[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JoachimSauer any specific reason, I should not upload an image?

Comment: Click my message, it's a link.

Comment: I suggest to stop the command and try again.

Comment: As per your screenshot, you are downloading blobs at a very slow rate: 29 KiB/s. It may depends by your connection of by the provider heavy load or low bandwidth.